# Generics and nullable reference types

Tags: c#, generics, nullable-reference-types

Quick question about the best way to design an API when using generics and nullable reference types. Ok, suppose you have the following type:

```
public class Demo<T>{
   T Get(int id){
      // get item from somewhere (remote call)
      // throws if remote call returns 404
   }
}
```

Now, I need to update the code so that it can return null instead of throwing in some cases. For instance, is there a way for me to say that `T` returned from `Get` might be `null` when an extra parameter is set to `true`:

```
T Get(int id, bool returnNullOn404 = true){
}
```

I've tried searching the null state attributes, but none seems to do what I want...

I'm thinking about going with an extra method which would look like this (and I could event discard the extra parameter):

```
public class Demo<T> where T:class {
   T Get(int id){
      // get item from somewhere (remote call)
      // throws if remote call returns 404
   }

   T? GetOrDefault(int id){
      // get item from somewhere (remote call)
      // returns null when remote call returns 404

   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it is user input - pass it from method signature. If it is compilation/startup time input - pass it through constructor or wrap it up into extension (it will be short-cut business logic). Leave only Get method - you can wrap it however you want.

Comment: How you've written it is pretty much how it's done. The TryGet pattern works very well for this, but unfortunately cannot be used in async methods which you almost certainly have if you're making a remote API call.

Comment: Another option - until natively supported - would be to use one of (pun intended) the work around libs that give you kind-of discriminated unions. Like OneOf or similar.

Comment: return default(T) ?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I'll go with the getordefault approach...